# Would there be any point in the input number having commas in Cobol

Tags: cobol

Say I have the picture PIC ----,---,---.99

If the input number was 999999999.99 it would display as 999,999,999.99
Should Cobol be left to handle the formatting so the input number doesn't need to be 999,999,999.99

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: I think you may be missing the point. COBOL, unlike other languages you may be familiar with, does not provide "format on display". For example in C you might use printf to format a numeric item in various ways. In COBOL you MOVE numeric data to a DISPLAY item with the desired format and then print (display/write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would format it the way you have it in the picture clause and not worry about having the user or the program enter the commas.

Answer (score 0):

COBOL is quite capable of doing it unless you are aware how to use DISPLAY USAGE clause effectively.

Refer [COBOL usage briefing](http://www.tonymarston.net/cobol/cobolstandards.html)

Comment: This is a nonsense answer and the link is to a very poor and dated document.